# Crash on Careers notification from the inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I have a notification concerning SO Careers in my inbox and it appears in the iOS app. Whenever I click on it, the app crashes but if I click on any other notification, it works perfectly fine and takes me to the respective post.

iPhone 5 iOS 7.0.6

v0.1.54

Comment: Fixed in v0.1.55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this!

This was a known issue that was indeed fixed in version 0.1.55.